# Function in a class string setAstring(Astring){//code} cannot change using set fuction, program crashes

Tags: c++, string, class, char

So I'm trying to use get/set functions, and I'm having a problem changing the default `Astring` using the set fuction. Program crashes after when I try to run with this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Example{

private:

    string m_Astring;

public:

    Example()
    {
       m_Astring="123456789012";
    }


    string setAstring(string Astring){m_Astring=Astring;}

    string getAstring(){return m_Astring;}

};

int main(){

Example test;
test.setAstring("250687354221");
cout<<test.getAstring()<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Here is a `'n'`.  Please add it to your *fuctions*, so they become proper *fu**n**ctions*.

Comment: You must be running an older version of the program because this wouldn't even compile.

Comment: Interesting, I'm using G++ 5.3.0 on Cygwin on Windows 7.  Program aborts when self-run.  Program does not abort when using GDB (Cygwin 7.10.1-1).  Ran the debugger at full speed, no crashes.  Single stepped with debugger, no issues.

Comment: It looks like it has something to do with your `setAstring` function being declared as returning a string, but nothing is returned. When I add a `return m_Astring;` in the `setAstring` method, it compiles and works.

Comment: Turn your warning level (and error reporting level) to maximum.  Visual Studio 2010 reports an error because your `setAstring` is not returning a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
string setAstring(string Astring){m_Astring=Astring;}
^^^^^^                                              ^^^^
return a string                                  no return of string
```

Your program crashes because you never returned anything from this function, and that is undefined.

(I suspect that the crash occurs when destroying the non-existent return value, but I haven't confirmed this.)

Comment: When compiled with Visual Studio 2010, I get the following error:  `error C4716: 'Example::setAstring' : must return a value`.

Comment: The function's return type should be changed to `void`.

Comment: I'm confused because I did the same thing, but with a double, and it works without return.

Comment: @ThanosSakis That's also undefined. It *seems* to work because "destroying" a `double` doesn't do anything. A `std::string` needs to deallocate its storage, among other things.